# @sys.email returns emails with other parts of the input amended, including whitespaces

Tags: dialogflow-es

@sys.email is sometimes returning extra parts of the user's input, including whitespaces. For instance:

input: "My e-mail is asdf@asdf.com"

And my @sys.email parameter is set as "is asdf@asdf.com"

I have around 150 training phrases in my intent on how to retrieve an email.

Like "My email is asdf@asdf.com" where the email is a parameter @sys.email:email, and a bunch which are email like examples, like "jsdnfknj@skjdnf.com".

I also added a template "My email is @sys.email:email".

I wonder if this is just a matter of more training needed or if there is something wrong with @sys.email.

Answer (score 0):

When you say...

> And my @sys.email parameter is set as "is asdf@asdf.com"

...do you mean that you've tagged "is asdf@asdf.com" as `@sys.email`? If so, make sure that you're only tagging the email address itself as `@sys.email` in your training phrases. Avoid tagging any extraneous words like "is".

Try cleaning up the entity tagging in your training phrases and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: No I did not tag that. That is what Dialogflow set in my parameter. Whenever I see this happenning, I go to training and correctly tag the email.